# extracting single value from json file to text file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have json file like this

```
{"lomx": "3 lokan", "idx": "kojemany94AaABAg", "moraku": "loerlaosjdis hejuyasdb", "keyword": "mekanobhaemausjek14232", "subhen": "koshdeksad"}
{"lomx": "3 lokan", "idx": "kojemany94AaABAg", "moraku": "londasjhdj", "keyword": "mekanobhaemausjek223232323", "subhen": "uahdioasdohoasd"}
{"lomx": "4 lokan", "idx": "jhalskdjhakljdisoaj", "moraku": "vajdlajd", "keyword": "mekanobhaemausjek3242312345", "subhen": "jshdajshdajhsdjhaksdjhsjdkahsdjkah"}
{"lomx": "4 lokan", "idx": "jahdjheuhasndashduasd", "moraku": "morkajsdhu", "keyword": "mekanobhaemausjek273232323232", "subhen": "lokamajuaksdksdasdaahsjdhkajhsdjkahs"}
```

i need to extract all the single values of "keyword" and add it to text file line by line

result should be something like this

```
mekanobhaemausjek14232
mekanobhaemausjek223232323
mekanobhaemausjek3242312345
mekanobhaemausjek273232323232
```

this is what i've tried

```
import json
data_file = 'c:\json_file.json'
json_data = open(data_file)
parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)

for mydata in parsed_json['keyword']
    print (mydata)
    f = open('jessers.txt','a')
    f.write("%s\n" % mydata)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Does that code run? What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'

Comment: Hint: you passed in an open file, not the **contents** of that file.

Comment: should i do read() ?

Comment: For Python errors, you should always add the error and traceback in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your program has a little problem, below is my test. There is no error now. Maybe you can modify it to suit your needs.

```
import json
data_file = 'c:\json_file.json'
json_data = open(data_file)
json_text = json_data.readlines()

for data_index in json_text:
    parsed_json = json.loads(data_index)
    print (parsed_json['keyword'])
```

OUtput:

```
mekanobhaemausjek14232
mekanobhaemausjek223232323
mekanobhaemausjek3242312345
mekanobhaemausjek273232323232
```

Comment: ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Can you show me the complete json_file.json?Maybe threre's some format related issue.

Comment: its exactly like the same i've posted in my question

Comment: Well, from the question title, I am wondering every one line is a json file or both the lines belong to one single json file? If they belong to one single file, the json file seems to have a format error.

Comment: I finally got the idea, I changed my answer, you can checked it out.

Comment: you're my hero <3 it worked and got what i wanted <3 god bless you sir :)

Comment: So (out of curiosity), what does this code fix in OP's attempt?